# Unable to split document using exsl:document in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, exslt

I'd like to split one XML file into multiple smalled files using XSLT. I read that this is possible using `exsl:document`. I've managed to sort-of get it to work except one minor issue — I can only seem to output one file. Here's my XML:

```
<People>
    <Person>
        <FirstName>John</FirstName>
        <LastName>Doe</LastName>
    </Person>
    <Person>
        <FirstName>Jack</FirstName>
        <LastName>White</LastName>
    </Person>
    <Person>
        <FirstName>Mark</FirstName>
        <LastName>Wall</LastName>
    </Person>
    <Person>
        <FirstName>John</FirstName>
        <LastName>Ding</LastName>
    </Person>
    <Person>
        <FirstName>Cyrus</FirstName>
        <LastName>Ding</LastName>
    </Person>
    <Person>
        <FirstName>Megan</FirstName>
        <LastName>Boing</LastName>
    </Person>
</People>
```

Here's my XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
  extension-element-prefixes="exsl"
  exclude-result-prefixes="exsl"
  version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="People/Person">
      <exsl:document href="{//FirstName}_{//LastName}.xml">
        <People>
          <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </People>
      </exsl:document>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Executing this using `xsltproc data.xsl data.xml` generates only one file called `John_Doe.xml`. I can't find any other files.

How can I split all the `Person` into the separate files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="People/Person">
      <exsl:document href="{//FirstName}_{//LastName}.xml">
        <People>
          <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </People>
      </exsl:document>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
```

to

```
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="People/Person">
      <exsl:document href="{FirstName}_{LastName}.xml">
        <People>
          <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </People>
      </exsl:document>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Martin, would you be able to explain why the `//` caused such a behaviour?

Comment: Your code creates a result document for each `Person`, but each time with the same name so you ended up with one file being created several times. The reason is that `//FirstName` selects all `FileName` descendants of the root node and the attribute value template `{//FirstName}` takes the string value of the first selected node. The same for `{//LastName}`. Instead you want to select the `FirstName` and `LastName` relative to each `Person` being the context node inside of the `for-each` body. That's what the relative path expressions `FirstName` and `LastName` do.